# Cyclic reference when trying to hide Repr

Tags: scala, types, circular-dependency

I've got the following traits:

```
sealed trait CommandLike[T, Repr <: CommandLike[T,_]]  extends CanBeEnabled[Repr]{
  def name: String
  def execute: T => Any
}

trait CanBeEnabled[Repr] {
  def enabled: Boolean
  def isEnabled = enabled
  def isDisabled = enabled
  def disable : Repr = setEnabled(enabled = false)
  def enable : Repr = setEnabled(enabled = true)
  def setEnabled(enabled: Boolean) : Repr
}
```

Now I want to have a list of commands:

```
val cmds = List[CommandLike[Unit, _]]()
```

This is annoying so I'd rather hide the Repr type parameter:

```
val cmds = List[Command[Unit]]()
```

So I need Command trait hiding the Repr:

```
trait Command[T] extends CommandLike[T, _ <: Command[T]]
```

But this gives me:

> illegal cyclic reference involving trait Command trait Command[T]
>   extends CommandLike[T, _ <: Command[T]]

Any ideas?
                                              ^

Answer (score 1):

```
trait CanBeEnabled {
  def enabled: Boolean
  def isEnabled = enabled
  def isDisabled = ! enabled
  def disable : this.type = setEnabled(enabled = false)
  def enable : this.type = setEnabled(enabled = true)
  def setEnabled(enabled: Boolean) : this.type
}

sealed trait Command[T]  extends CanBeEnabled {
  def name: String
  def execute: T => Any
}
```

isDisabled should be ! enabled ...

Comment: Reuben, can you give us an example of the concrete instance of Command which acctually compiles, i.e. class X extends Command[Unit]{...}. Also I should be able to do: var x = new X; x = x.disable. Can you check if it compiles before you post it, please.

Answer (score 0):

For you `trait Command` implementation of `CommandLike`, `Repr` is `Command[T]`, so you should have:

```
Command[T] extend CommandLike[T, Command[T]]
```

The same way the collection library defines, for example,

```
Seq[T] extends ... with SeqLike[T, Seq[T]]
```

---

@Reuben's answer works as well, with different semantics:

If later, you define another command:

```
class CustomCommand[T] extends Command[T]
```

- in the `this.type` case (singleton type), `setEnabled` will return a `CustomCommand[T]`,
- and in the `Repr` case I describe above, `setEnabled` will return a `Command[T]` since that's how `Repr` has been defined.

Both are fine, it all depends on what you actually need. For utility methods like this, `this.type` seems better though.